# relationship between forms authentication provider and membership provider in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

What is the difference between these two providers. Do i have to implement both of them for custom authentication?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One is for authentication, the other is for role-based authorisation.

You do not need to implement both, that would down to your own requirements. If you only need to log people in, then use FormsAuthentication. If you need more than that, implement both.